Copy automatically data from sheets to another
I would like to know how to transpose automatically (if vba, no button) the data of 10 identic tables (B5:E100) in the same excel file into one central table on the last sheet (Sheet 11), without taking into account the empty lines.

Are you trying to append multiples tables from multiple sheets into one, then using Power Query would be easiest way to do, unless you are specifically trying to do it using VBA. Using Excel Formulas to transpose multiple or append multiple is not a great idea btw as well the Excel will crash at some point!! Using VSTACK() is possible, but it totally depends on the number of rows or data you would do!

Ok, in that case, i would like to do it using vba specifically. I have 950 rows possible.

10x sheets right so total of 950 rows or 950*10?, is there any chances that it will increase in future? I wont be able to help you with VBA but those who help on this particular language, would be asking you to show what you have tried on your end, and where you are failing to achieve with the existing code. Personally, i will use Power Query its way easy then any other thing when its just to append the data. Do it once and enjoy the fruit rest of the time as long as your are using that particular sheet. If its only 950 consider using VSTACK() provided it wont increase any further.

A Worksheet Activate: Copy Data From Specific Sheets to a Summary Sheet

This will run automatically each time you activate the destination sheet i.e. the data may be incorrect while another sheet is active.


Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet11

In Excel, right-click the destination tab and select View Code. Copy the following code into the window that opened.

    Option Explicit
    
    Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
        CreateSummary Me
    End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1

In VBE, right-click the correct project in the Project Explorer (Ctrl+R) and select Insert-->Module. Copy the following code into the window that opened.

Option Explicit

' You could assign this one to a button (Forms control).
Sub CreateSummaryInSheet11()
    CreateSummary ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet11")
End Sub

Sub CreateSummary(ByVal dws As Worksheet)
    
    Dim SRC_WORKSHEET_NAMES() As Variant: SRC_WORKSHEET_NAMES = Array( _
        "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", _
        "Sheet6", "Sheet7", "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet10")
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW_ADDRESS As String = "B5:E5"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    
    If IsNumeric(Application _
            .Match(dws.Name, SRC_WORKSHEET_NAMES, 0)) Then
        MsgBox "The destination sheet is listed in the source sheets array!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = dws.Parent
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = dws.Range(SRC_FIRST_ROW_ADDRESS).Columns.Count
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Clear existing.
    dcell.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dcell.Row + 1, cCount).Clear
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, sfrg As Range, slcell As Range
    Dim rCount As Long, n As Long
    
    For n = LBound(SRC_WORKSHEET_NAMES) To UBound(SRC_WORKSHEET_NAMES)
        Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_WORKSHEET_NAMES(n))
        Set sfrg = sws.Range("B5:E5")
        Set slcell = sfrg.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - sfrg.Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If Not slcell Is Nothing Then
            rCount = slcell.Row - sfrg.Row + 1
            Set srg = sfrg.Resize(rCount)
            srg.Copy dcell
            Set dcell = dcell.Offset(rCount)
        End If
    Next n
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Summary created in range """ & dws.Range( _
        DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS, dcell.Offset(-1, cCount - 1)).Address(0, 0) _
        & """ of sheet """ & dws.Name & """.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

